# Integration using induction question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, induction

Assume $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and arbitrarily often differentiable on $(0, 1)$ (i.e.
$f$ is smooth). Denote by $f^{m}$ the $m\text{-th}$ derivative of $f$ with $m∈\mathbb{N}$ and set $f^{0}:=f$.
Prove via induction that the following formula holds for arbitrary $m∈\mathbb{N}$,

$$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx =\sum_{r=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}f^{r-1}(1)}{(n+r)!}+(-1)^m\int_0^1 
\frac{x^{n+m} f^m(x)}{(n+m)!}dx$$

where $n∈\mathbb{N}$ is fixed.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. :p

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @JoogieBoogie Do you know how a proof by induction is done?

Comment: Yes, we prove the statement to be true for n=1, then assume n=k and then prove the statement to be true for n=k+1. But using these steps in this question lead me to nowhere. How do I use the integration by parts and induction?

Comment: @JoogieBoogie Ok, but you have to do induction on $m$, not on $n$. Fix $n$. The case $m=0$ is trivial, the induction step is done by integrating by parts.